# Incorrect plotting of e function using Tikz plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I am trying to plot a couple functions in Latex, including an absolute and e function, these are depicted in the following image;
[image]

However using the code below, the image that results is:
[image]

What is going wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $t$,
    ylabel = {$f(t)$},
]
%Below the red parabola is defined
\addplot [
    domain=-0.5:0.5, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
]
{sqrt(abs(x))};
\addlegendentry{$\sqrt{|t|}$}
%Here the blue parabloa is defined
\addplot [
    domain=-0.5:0.5, 
    samples=100, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    {abs(x)};
\addlegendentry{$|t|$}
%Here the orange parabloa is defined
\addplot [
    domain=-0.5:0.5, 
    samples=200, 
    color=orange,
    ]
    {e^(abs(x)-1)};
 \addlegendentry{$e^{|t|}-1$}
 %Here the purple parabloa is defined
\addplot [
    domain=-0.5:0.5, 
    samples=100, 
    color=purple,
    ]
    {e^(abs(2*x)-1)};
\addlegendentry{$e^{|2t|}-1$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{M1} \label{fig:M1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (MWE).

Comment: @TeXnician Is it correct now?

Comment: Now it is compilable.

Comment: A couple of things:too few samples, giving you the blunt tip on `$\sqrt{|t|}$`; Don't you mean `e^(abs(x))-1`? That would be `$\mathrm{e}^{|t|}-1$` as indicated, and would make sense as `e^0=1` and you want `orange_curve(0)=0`, so `orange_curve` should be `(e^x)-1` (superfluous brackets for emphasis)

Comment: Note also that with an even number of samples and a domain that is symmetric around 0, you will not get a sample exactly at x=0. So try 101 samples, instead of 100.

Answer (score 3):

At least your red plot can be improved by increasing the samples with:

[image: plots]

```
\addplot [
    domain=-0.5:0.5, 
    samples=1000, 
    color=red,
    smooth,
]
{sqrt(abs(x))};
```

But `pgfplots` is right plotting your functions: the purple and orange one can not go to y-value 0 (manually calculating results in 1/e for x=0).

*Update:* Correcting your typos:

[image: corrected plots]

```
%Here the orange parabloa is defined
\addplot [
    domain=-0.5:0.5, 
    samples=201, 
    color=orange,
    smooth
    ]
    {e^(abs(x))-1};
 \addlegendentry{$e^{|t|}-1$}
 %Here the purple parabloa is defined
\addplot [
    domain=-0.5:0.5, 
    samples=201, 
    color=purple,
    smooth
    ]
    {e^(abs(2*x))-1};
\addlegendentry{$e^{|2t|}-1$}
```

Comment: I think the OP has a typo in the formula definition -- it doesn't match the legend.

Comment: 5000 is a bit overkill, try 201. (Maybe more for `sqrt(abs(x))`.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks for pointing that out. That was my test document before I looked at the formulas and corrected them...